# changing of the derivative function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, fluid-dynamics

My question deals with the continuity equation and the changing of the derivative function.

The continuity equation for one-dimensional flow requires that

$$ \frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial x} = - \phi \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} $$

From some math steps that are performed (not shown here), the change in pressure with respect to time is found to be:

$$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = \frac{g \sqrt{c+1}}{\sqrt{c+g}} \cdot P'_o $$

where $$g \equiv \left(1-\frac{x}{L}\right)$$

Since $ \rho = PM/(RT) $ and $g = 1 - x/L $, then we can substitute our relations back into our continuity equation as: $$ \frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial g} = \frac{ \phi LMP'_o \sqrt{c+1}}{RT} \cdot \frac{g}{\sqrt{c+g}}$$

As can be seen, our LHS changed:  $$ \frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial x} \rightarrow \frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial g} $$  with a corresponding change in the numerator on the RHS by multiplying by L.

My questions is, What are the steps mathematically to show that this is true? I feel that it is simple algebra saying that $$\frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial g} = \frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial \big(\frac{L-x}{L}\big)} $$

therefore: $$\frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial ({L-x})} = \frac{ \phi LMP'_o \sqrt{c+1}}{RT} \cdot \frac{g}{\sqrt{c+g}} $$

And we can leave it written as $\frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial g} = \frac{ \phi LMP'_o \sqrt{c+1}}{RT} \cdot \frac{g}{\sqrt{c+g}}  $ ?

I hope that someone can clear this up for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Can we get a join on the [tag:algebra-precalculus] and [tag:fluid-dynamics] tags?

Comment: @Arkamis -- I'm relatively new to this site/LaTex/type of forum.  If you are asking me to edit the tags could you please explain how or provide me with a link? I will gladly change the tags.

Comment: I'm not; my comment was meta-commentary on the unlikelihood of algebra-precalculus and fluid dynamics going together. One of those things is generally substantially more complicated than the other, so you don't see them together very often ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a direct application of the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). Seeing $g$ as a function of $x$, the following is true :

$$ 
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial g}.
$$

Since $g=1-\frac{x}{L}$, we find

$$
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{L}\frac{\partial}{\partial g},
$$

or

$$
    \frac{\partial}{\partial g} = -L\frac{\partial}{\partial x}.
$$

Plugging this result in your previous calculations gives

$$
    \begin{align}
        \frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial g} &= -L\frac{\partial(\rho v)}{\partial x} \\
        &= L\phi \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{PM}{RT}\right) \\
        &= \frac{L\phi M}{RT}\frac{g\sqrt{c+1}}{\sqrt{c+g}}P_0'.
    \end{align}
$$